# Table is not within the margins

Tags: tables

I have set margins using the `geometry` package (for my resume). I have put up the table but it is going beyond the margins. And, how to bring the **Operating System** text between the two lines? Please help!

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
\hline
\textbf{Operating Systems} & Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8 \\
& Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora \\
\hline
\textbf{Programming Languages} & C, C++, Core Java, Core Python, Basic C\#\\
\hline
\textbf{Web Technologies} & HTML5, CSS3, XML, Javascript, Node.js, PHP, JSP, ASP.NET\\
\hline
\textbf{Databases} & Oracle 10g, MySQL 5 \\
\hline
\textbf{Packages} & Netbeans 8.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, Eclipse 5\\
\hline
\textbf{Linux} & Bash Shell Scripting
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one option that *abuses* `multirow`. Generally this shouldn't be done. But for this case it works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
   %\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  %% this is short.
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}lX}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Operating Systems} & Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8,  Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora       \\
\hline
Programming Languages              & C, C++, Core Java, Core Python, Basic C\#                       \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Web Technologies}  & HTML5, CSS3, XML, Javascript, Node.js, PHP, JSP, ASP.NET        \\
\hline
Databases                          & Oracle 10g, MySQL 5                                             \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Packages}          & Netbeans 8.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, Eclipse 5 \\
\hline
Linux                              & Bash Shell Scripting                                                                                       
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is another version without abusing anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
   %\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  %% this is short.
\usepackage{array,calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{\textbf{Programming Languages}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylen-4\tabcolsep\relax}}
\newcommand{\col}[1]{%       %% code stolen from egreg
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}L@{}}
  \strut #1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
\hline
Operating Systems     & \col{Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8,  Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora}       \\
\hline
Programming Languages & \col{C, C++, Core Java, Core Python, Basic C\#}                       \\
\hline
Web Technologies      & \col{HTML5, CSS3, XML, Javascript, Node.js, PHP, JSP, ASP.NET}        \\
\hline
Databases             & \col{Oracle 10g, MySQL 5}                                             \\
\hline
Packages              & \col{Netbeans 8.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, Eclipse 5} \\
\hline
Linux                 & \col{Bash Shell Scripting}                                            
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, you will be better off using a list instead of `tabular`.

Comment: The long list of `geometry` options, `[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]`, can be written a bit more succinctly as `[margin=1in]`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I agree. But the OP may want to keep different margins on different sides. That is why I didn't touch that. I will add a comment though. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To force a tabular environment to occupy precisely the width of the text block without performing any calculations by hand, it's convenient to load the `tabularx` package and to specify the overall width of the `tabularx` environment as `\textwidth`. The package also provides a new column type named `X`, whose width is computed as a residual (`\textwidth` minus the widths of all other columns); this is what eliminates calculating column widths explicitly. In addition, it's straightforward to define a modified `X` column type that typesets its contents in ragged-right mode rather than in fully justified mode.

Separately, since the contents of all cells in the first column appear to be typeset in bold, it's convenient to write `>{\bfseries}l` instead of just `l` as the column specifier for the first column. That way, you needn't write `\textbf` explicitly in every single cell in the first column.

(These two suggestions are also used by @HarishKumar in the first of this two solutions.)

In addition, you may want to consider using the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- specifically, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` -- and dropping all other horizontal lines completely. Instead of the intermediate horizontal rules, which provide mainly visual clutter, consider simply adding a bit of extra vertical whitespace.

Incidentally, you will note that I would *not* adjust the vertical position of the strings "Operating Systems", "Web Technologies", and "Packages" in the first column. I think they look just fine the way they are placed by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l Y @{}}
\toprule
Operating Systems & Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora \\ \addlinespace
Programming Languages & C, C++, Core Java, Core Python, Basic C\#\\ \addlinespace
Web Technologies & HTML5, CSS3, XML, Javascript, Node.js, PHP, JSP, ASP.NET\\ \addlinespace
Databases & Oracle 10g, MySQL 5 \\ \addlinespace
Packages & Netbeans 8.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, Eclipse 5\\ \addlinespace
Linux & Bash Shell Scripting\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```